# Batch script: Rename copied files to match origin folder

Tags: batch-file

I'm using this code to copy one random file from each sub-folder in a parent folder (E:\"New folder") to a new destination folder (E:\samples\"New folder") [it works great]:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd E:\"New folder"
set t=0
for /d %%i in (*) do (
    cd "%%i"
    set /A t+=1
    set n[!t!]=0
    for %%f in (*.jpeg *.jpg *.gif *.bmp *.png) do (
       set /A n[!t!]+=1
       set "file[!n!]=%%f"
    )
    set /A "rand=(n[!t!]*%random%)/32768+1"
    copy "!file[%rand%]!" E:\samples\"New folder"
    cd..
)
pause
```

However, i need to have the copied files be re-named according to their origin folder like so:

If a file named DC20140912.jpg originated from a sub-folder named "Italy2014", I need it to be renamed "Italy2014.jpg", a file originating from a sub-folder named "Rome2015" to be renamed "Rome2015.jpg" and so on.

Only one file is copied from each sub-folder so no risk of filename clashes.

Please help

Comment: Sadly, as I have explained in another of your questions, this routine may seem to work, but it actually merely fails to fail. The `for/d` command will replace `%random%` with a random number and `%rand%` with *nothing*. You are counting files into `n[t]` but since `n` is not set, `!n!` will be replaced by *nothing* so the filename will be assigned to `file[]` and will always be the last name of the group selected. The `copy` command will copy `file[]` - always the same file - the last one selected in the directory. Sure, it will select **a** file each time, but always the same one.

Comment: Thank you! made this change (@LotPings) did too, works great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since the extensions differ you will have to extract them or store them seperately.
- this batch stores them too:

---

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Base=C:\Test"
Set "Dest=Q:\Test\2017-04\24"
Cd /D "%Base%"
set t=0
for /d %%i in (*) do (
    cd "%%i"
    set /A "n=0"
    for %%f in (*.jpeg *.jpg *.gif *.bmp *.png) do (
       set /A "n+=1"
       set "file[!n!]=%%f"
       set "ext[!n!]=%%~xf"
    )
    If !n! gtr 0 (
        set /A "rand=(!n!*!random!)/32768+1"
        Call Set "file=%%file[!rand!]%%"
        Call Set "ext=%%ext[!rand!]%%"
        Echo rand=!rand! n=!n! copy "!file!" "%Dest%\%%~ni!ext!"
        copy "!file!" "%Dest%\%%~ni!ext!" >Nul 2>&1
    )
    cd..
)
```

**Edit** Need to use !random! and Call Set

Comment: what if I run the script separately for each file ext. (deleting all but say *.jpeg), how will it look like then?

Comment: The currently processed folder path is in `%%i`, `%%~ni` takes only the last. With a fix extension the file name is i.e. `%%~ni.jpg`

Comment: There were some flaws due to the outer loop. (have to use !random!)

Comment: Check mark as anwer and/or vote up, read [about reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)